# Is it possible to display the attributes according to the IDP selected while signUp

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have configured Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, Google and AzureAD as our providers using Custom SignUp/SignIn Policy.

We have a requirement to ask for Business Email when a user sign's up using social Idp(Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, Google) but not when Azure AD selected(as they are already using their business email).

I have added the new attribute to this section,

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are wanting the end-user experience to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must ascertain whether an enterprise account or a social account has been logged in.

For example:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ContosoProfile">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="contosoAuthentication" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

and:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Secondly, you must create two technical profiles for the account registration: one technical profile for the enterprise account registration that excludes the business email and the other technical profile for the social account registration that includes it.

For example:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Enterprise">
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Social">
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Thirdly, based on the `authenticationSource` claim, you must invoke one or the other technical profile.

For example:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Enterprise" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Enterprise" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>contosoAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```